# Two javascript webworkers print output consecutively - Why not concurrently?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I'm looking into webworkers and multithreading/concurrency in JavaScript.
I'm trying to "prove" it to myself by running the following programs

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Worker 2</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
var myFunction = function() {

    worker = new Worker('worker.js');

    worker.postMessage('cowboy');

    for (var i=0; i<500; i++) {
        var d = new Date();
        var h = d.getHours(); 
        var m = d.getMinutes();
        var s = d.getSeconds();
        var ms = d.getMilliseconds();
        console.log("main: " + h + ":" + m + ":" + s + ":" + ms);
    }

};
window.onload=myFunction;
```

**worker.js**

```
self.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage);

function receiveMessage(e) {
    for (var i=0; i<500; i++) {
        var d = new Date();
        var h = d.getHours(); // => 9
        var m = d.getMinutes(); // =>  30
        var s = d.getSeconds(); // => 51
        var ms = d.getMilliseconds();
        console.log("worker: " + h + " " + m + ":" + s + ":" + ms);
     }
}
```

What happens is that all the console.log statements from main.js are printed first, then all the console.log statements from worker.js e.g.

[Console.log screenshop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxB31.png)

What I would have thought is that the printouts would be interspersed e.g.

```
main: 21:50:10:707
worker: 21 50:10:708
main: 21:50:10:709
main: 21:50:10:710
worker: 21 50:10:711
worker: 21 50:10:712
worker: 21 50:10:713
main: 21 50:10:714
```

Why is this not happening and is there any way to demonstrate this as above?

Comment: It could be the `console` mechanism that's acting as a "choke point".

Comment: @Pointy Yes, it looks like that was the case.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert, but here's my educated guess:

`postMessage` is asynchronous. When you call it, it *queues* the message to be sent, and it will actually be sent when the current "thread" (ie. the "log 500 console messages" bit) has finished. At that point it is free to send the message to the worker, which will be able to log its own messages.

To test this, try wrapping `setTimeout(function() { ... }, 1);` around the loop... In theory you should now see the worker's messages first, then the main thread's.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was looking for both "threads" to be run simultaneously not the worker one before the main one though. The solution I found was to make 2 workers instead of one and move the for loop from the main.js to the new worker. I'll post the code later.